# OpenAM and Yii2 single sign on

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, openam

I’m looking for a way to properly implement SSO with Yii2. So i found out about OpenAM and wonder if it can work with Yii2.

Please provide some advice or documents about this cause i can't find it anywhere.

I'm using Yii2 basic app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authentication it seems you could achieve SSO by using either an Web Policy Agent and build some implementation of yii\web\IdentityInterface  that just reads data set by the agent.

You may also use mod_auth_mellon in the Apache http server to achieve SAML based SSO and build an implementation of the interface. OpenAM would act as the SAML IdP.

If your app has RESTful WebServices you may use OIDC instead of SAML, e.g. by using https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc in Apache http server. OpenAM would act as the OIDC provider.